# bash while loop "eats" my space characters

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I am trying to parse a huge text file, say 200mb.

the text file contains some strings

```
123
1234
12345
12345
```

so my script looked like

```
while read line ; do
echo "$line"
done <textfile
```

however using this above method, my string `"     12345"` gets truncated to `"12345"`

I tried using

```
sed -n "$i"p textfile
```

but the the throughput is reduced from 27 to 0.2 lines per second, which is inacceptable ;-)

any Idea howto solve this?

Comment: iam sorry, I have added the four 0x20 in front of the string lines, but the editor seemed to ignore it.

Comment: So the issue is fixed?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this at all. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and **seriously** consider doing it the concise, robust, efficient, portable standard UNIX way with `awk '{print}' textfile`. I assume you plan to do more than just print each line.

Comment: it does a rather slow calculation with each line, so reading fast from the file is not an issue, and it is not THE important part of the script. Thanks for the hint I'll read through it

Comment: The rather slow calculation you mention would probably happen in the blink  of an eye if you used awk instead of shell to do it. Post a followup question if you're interested in seeing the right approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be what you're looking for:

```
while IFS= read line; do
echo "$line"
done < textfile
```

The safest method is to use `read -r` in comparison to just `read` which will skip interpretation of special characters (thanks Walter A):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
echo "$line"
done < textfile
```

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line` is the best way to protect the input

Answer (score 9):

You want to echo the lines without a fieldsep:

```
while IFS="" read line; do
    echo "$line"
done <<< " 12345"
```

When you also want to skip interpretation of special characters, use

```
while IFS="" read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done <<< " 12345"
```

You can write the IFS without double quotes:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done <<< " 12345"
```

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# read whole file into array
readarray -t aMyArray < <(cat textfile)

# echo each line of the array
# this will preserve spaces
for i in "${aMyArray[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

- readarray -- read lines from standard input
- -t -- omit trailing newline character
- aMyArray -- name of array to store file in
- < <() -- execute command; redirect stdout into array
- cat textfile -- file you want to store in variable
- for i in "${aMyArray[@]}" -- for every element in aMyArray
- "" -- needed to maintain spaces in elements
- ${ [@]} -- reference all elements in array
- do echo "$i"; -- for every iteration of "$i" echo it
- "" -- to maintain variable spaces
- $i -- equals each element of the array aMyArray as it cycles through
- done -- close for loop

**OPTION 2:**

In order to accommodate your larger file you could do this to help alleviate the work and speed up the processing.

```
#!/bin/bash

sSearchFile=textfile
sSearchStrings="1|2|3|space"

while IFS= read -r line; do

    echo "${line}"

done < <(egrep "${sSearchStrings}" "${sSearchFile}")
```

This will grep the file (faster) before it cycles it through the while command.  Let me know how this works for you.  Notice you can add multiple search strings to the $sSearchStrings variable.

**OPTION 3:**

and an all in one solution to have a text file with your search criteria and everything else combined...

```
#!/bin/bash

# identify file containing search strings
sSearchStrings="searchstrings.file"

while IFS= read -r string; do

# if $sSearchStrings empty read in strings
    [[ -z $sSearchStrings ]] && sSearchStrings="${string}"
# if $sSearchStrings not empty read in $sSearchStrings "|" $string
    [[ ! -z $sSearchStrings ]] && sSearchStrings="${sSearchStrings}|${string}"

# read search criteria in from file
done <"${sSearchStrings}"

# identify file to be searched
sSearchFile="text.file"

while IFS= read -r line; do

    echo "${line}"

done < <(egrep "${sSearchStrings}" "${sSearchFile}")
```

Comment: @TobySpeight, fair enough and thank you for reminding me to be more thorough.  I've updated the answer to contain more information.

Comment: Thanks for that code. The file is 33gb i fear as the machine only has 1gb of ram, this could cause some serious issues, lol. But I have stored the code for future projects!

Comment: @SebastianHeyn, Yes, that's a lot larger than the ~200Mb listed above.  I would not use this solution for that file.  I'm glad you got your answer though!

Comment: @SebastianHeyn, I updated my answer using an amalgam of the previous answers that should result in faster processing of a very large text file.  Please let me know how this turns out for you.

Comment: @jgshawkey yes the 200mb was a test file ;-)